# How to check how many variables (masks) declared in Regexp (ruby)?

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have a regexp with some arbitrary amount of capturing groups:

```
pattern = /(some)| ..a lot of masks combined.... |(other)/
```

Is there any way to determine a number of that groups?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Could you please clarify with some example input and the kind of output you want to get?

Comment: You mean, how to determine how many capturing groups a regex has?

Comment: It would be [easy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures) if you used named captures instead.

Comment: Hmmm... that's a good option! But in my case it can be hard to mantain, cause I'm going to combine arbitrary number of patterns and there may be name conflicts.

Comment: what do you need it for, after all? I sense an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JanDvorak right! That is an XY problem most likely. I needed this check to validate rules for some kind of parser. Each rule supposed to know what to do with variables if they occured. And it's important to match number of groups in pattern with number of declared variables. But it shouldn't be done during runtime (like I was going to do initially), instead I'll use testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can always find a string that matches the regex you are given, then it suffices to match it against the regex, and [look at the match data length](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-length). However, determining whether a regexp *has* a string that it matches is np-hard<sup>[1]</sup>. This is only feasible if you know in advance what kind of regexes you'll be getting.

The next best best method in the [`Regexp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) class is [`Regexp#source`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-source) or [`Regexp#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s). However, we need to parse the regex if we do this.

I can't speak for the future, but **as of Ruby 2.0**, there is no better method in the `Regexp` core class.

A left parenthesis denotes a literal left parenthesis, if preceded by an unescaped backslash. A backslash is unescaped unless an unescaped backslash precedes. So, a character is escaped iff preceded by an odd number of backslashes.

An unescaped left parenthesis denotes a capturing group iff not followed by a question mark. With a question mark, it can mean various things: `(?'name')` and `(?<name>)` denote a named capturing group. Named and unnamed capturing groups cannot coexist in the same regex, however<sup>[2]</sup>. `(?:)` denote non-capturing groups. This is a special case of `(?flags-flags:)`. `(?>)` denote atomic groups. `(?=)`, `(?!)`, `(?<=)` and `(?<!)` denote lookaround. `(?#)` denote comments.

Ruby regexp engine supports comments in regexes. Considering them in the main regex would be very difficult. We can try to strip them if we really want to support these, but supporting them fully will get messy due to the possibility of inline flags turning extended mode (and thus line comments) on and off in ways that a regular expression cannot capture. I will go ahead and **not support unescaped parentheses in regex comments**<sup>[3]</sup>.

We want to count:

- the number of left parentheses `\(`
- that are not escaped by a backslash `(?<!(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\)` (read: not preceded by an odd number of backslashes that are not preceded by yet another backslash) and
- that are not followed by a question mark `(?!\?)`

Ruby doesn't support unbounded lookbehind, but if we reverse the source first, we can rewrite the first assertion slightly: `(?!(?:\\\\)*(?!\\))`. The second assertion becomes a lookbehind: `(?<!\?)`.

the whole solution

```
def count_groups(regexp)
  # named capture support:
  # named_count = regexp.named_captures.count 
  # return named_count if named_count > 0

  # main: 
  test = /(?!<\?)\((?!(?:\\\\)*(?!\\))/
  regexp.source.scan(test).count
end
```

---

[1]: we can show the NP-hardness by converting the satisfiability problem to it:

- AND: `xy` (`x` must be an assertion)
- OR: `x|y`
- NOT: `(?!x)`
- atoms: `(?=1)`, `(?=.1)`, `(?=..1)`, ..., `(?!1)`, `(?!.1)`...

example(XOR): `/^(?:(?=1)(?!.1)|(?!1)(?=.1))..$/`

this extends to NP-completeness for any class of regexes that can be tested in polynomial time. This includes any regex with no nested repetition (or repeated backreferences to repetition or recursion) and with bounded nesting depth of optional matches.

[2]: `/((?<name>..)..)../.match('abcdef').to_a` returns `['abcdef', 'ab']`, indicating that unnamed capturing groups are ignored when named capturing groups are present. Tested in Ruby 1.9.3

[3]: Inline comments start with `(?#` and end with `)`. They cannot contain an unescaped right parenthesis, but they can contain an unescaped left parenthesis. These can be stripped easily (even though we have to sprinkle the "unescaped" regex everywhere), are the lesser evil, but they're also less likely to contain anunescaped left parenthesis.

Line comments start with `#` and end with a newline. *These are only treated as comments in the extended mode*. Outside the extended mode, they match the literal `#` and newline. This is still easy, even if we have to consider escaping *again*. Determining if the regex has the extended flag set is not too difficult, but the flag modifier groups are a different beast entirely.

Even with Ruby's awesome [recursive regexes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Subexpression+Calls), merely determining if a previously-open group modifying the extended mode is already closed would yield a *very* nasty regex (even if you replace one by one and don't have to skip comments, you have to account for escaping). It wouldn't be pretty (even with interpolation) and it wouldn't be fast.